# TFS: Check if local file is latest version from within script

Tags: tfs

Ref: Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015:
How do i check from within a batch- or Powershell-script for a given file under TFS source control, if a local file is or is not equal to the latest version on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use tf.exe, which comes with Visual Studio. Here are some different options using PowerShell. This could also be written in batch with a few changes.

Assume the following:

```
# Change directory to the folder containing your file.
Set-Location "D:\MyProjects\Project1\Logic"

# File to evaluate
$file = "Program.cs"

# Using the Visual Studio 2015 Common Tools System Variable to find tf.exe
$tfExe = "$env:VS140COMNTOOLS\..\IDE\TF.exe"
```

---

**1:** Use `get /preview`, which will preview if it can get a newer version.

```
& cmd /c "`"$tfExe`" get $file /preview"
```

Result if latest:

```
All files are up to date.
```

Result if not latest:

```
D:\MyProjects\Project1\Logic:
Replacing Program.cs
```

[Get Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command)

---

**2:** Use `difference /format:Brief` with `status`, which will tell you if there are differences locally, but no pending changes

```
& cmd /c "`"$tfExe`" difference $file /format:Brief"
& cmd /c "`"$tfExe`" status $file"
```

Result if latest:

```
Comparing local to latest: D:\MyProjects\Project1\Logic\Program.cs
There are no pending changes.
```

Result if not latest:

```
Comparing local to latest: D:\MyProjects\Project1\Logic\Program.cs
Program.cs: files differ
There are no pending changes.
```

[Difference Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/difference-command)

[Status Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/status-command)

---

**3:** Use `info`, which will show the local changeset and the server changeset, and you can see if they're different.

```
& cmd /c "`"$tfExe`" info $file"
```

Result:

```
Local information:
  Local path : D:\MyProjects\Project1\Logic\Program.cs
  Server path: $/MyProjects/Project1/Logic/Program.cs
  Changeset  : 2842
  Change     : none
  Type       : file
Server information:
  Server path  : $/MyProjects/Project1/Logic/Program.cs
  Changeset    : 2845
  Deletion ID  : 0
  Lock         : none
  Lock owner   : 
  Last modified: Friday, December 15, 2017 4:32:57 PM
  Type         : file
  File type    : utf-8
  Size         : 2835
```

[Info/Properties Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/properties-or-info-command)

---

There is also [LocalVersions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/localversions-command), which will tell you the local changeset of your file, and [History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/history-command) which will show all changesets of the file.